# Finding the difference (subtraction) in SQL

Tags: sql, difference

I am trying to find the difference in sales of tshirts from year 2013 and year 2014. These 2 queries on their own do give me the correct number of sales. However, I don't know how to compare these two numbers and return their difference. Any help?

```
select sum(qty)
from customers natural join orders
natural join itemsordered
natural join items
where orderdate >= '2014-01-01' and orderdate <= '2014-12-31' and description ='tshirt';

select sum(qty)
from customers natural join orders
natural join itemsordered
natural join items
where orderdate >= '2013-01-01' and orderdate <= '2013-12-31' and description ='tshirt';
```

Database used is as follows:

Customers(custID, name, firstOrderDate, city)

Managers(mgrID, name, salary)
Stores(storeID, city, mgrID)
Items(itemID, description, size, color)
Inventory(storeID, itemID, qty)
Orders(orderID, orderDate, custID)
ItemsOrdered(itemID, orderID, qty)

Comment: What database are you using?  And to be clear, you want the change in total items for the year?  So only a single number is returned from the query, yes?

Comment: Right, the value returned should be an integer. However, it should always be a positive integer whether the sales went up by 500 or down by 500 year over year, 500 should be returned (not -500). I updated the original post to show the database information.

Comment: Got the absolute value portion to work. Thanks, this problem is completely solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a case expression inside the SUM() function. Here you filter all records for just the 2 years you are interested in, then using case, sum year 2013 records, sum 2014 records and then subtract one of these from the other. Like this:

```
select
      sum(case when orderdate >= '2013-01-01' and orderdate < '2014-01-01' then qty end) yr2013
    , sum(case when orderdate >= '2014-01-01' and orderdate < '2015-01-01' then qty end) yr2014

    , sum(case when orderdate >= '2014-01-01' and orderdate < '2015-01-01' then qty end)
    - sum(case when orderdate >= '2013-01-01' and orderdate < '2014-01-01' then qty end) diff

from customers 
natural join orders
natural join itemsordered
natural join items
where orderdate >= '2013-01-01' and orderdate < '2015-01-01' and description ='tshirt';
```

Please note the small change I've introduced into the date range logic. Using a combination of "greater than and equal to" with "less than (the next day)" is more reliable than involving equal to in both the lower and upper boundaries. (& It works for any date/time precision without causing any gaps or overlaps.)

note: the above should be reasonably generic but the method for handling dates will differ depending on database type (which was unknown when written)

Comment: This does work. However, I am trying to just return a positive integer and in my database, I am getting -86. I tried adding abs() but ran into an error.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to pivot the two year rows onto a single row and perform the diff.

```
select diff = abs(y13_qty - y14_qty) from
(select yr = year(orderdate), qty
from customers natural join orders
natural join itemsordered
natural join items
where year(orderdate) in (2013,2014) and description ='tshirt')
pivot (sum(qty) as qty for yr in (2013 as 'y13', 2014 as 'y14'))
```

(not familiar with oracle so pivot syntax might be off)